What is the URI deeplink to Xbox Library's "Manage Updates" screen in UWP? ex: 'library://path/to/manage/updates'
In my uwp app (xbox, webview2, react) I can deep link to (open) the Xbox's Library app using the library:// Protocol URI (found here) like this:
  await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("library://"));

But I haven't been able to work out the path to this Manage Updates screen (Library > Manage > Updates):
Screenshot of the xbox library's Manage Updates screen
I've tried this, which according to these docs "... will launch the Library page." BUT it only opens the store homepage.
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store://downloadsandupdates"));

I've also tried all of these library:// URI protocols without any luck

  await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("library://"));
  await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("library://manage"));
  await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("library://manage/updates"));
  await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("library://Manage"));
  await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("library://Manage/updates"));
  await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("library://manageupdates"));


For UWP, there is API StoreContext can check for updates, as well as those for downloading and apply updates.

This looks very promising! I'll give it a shot and report back
